# NetworkImage error Could not instantiate image code

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-image

So what I'm doing is I'm fetching data from an API and it provides an array with the image path in it.

I'm using `NetworkImage` to show the image.

It looks like this:

```
FadeInImage(
image: NetworkImage(
'https://sampleonly.com/storage/images/posts/image/20190918UTC054308606.jpg'
)
)
```

**EDIT**

If I use a static url (I copied the imagepath of the first index) to replace all images, the error doesn't show.

Comment: is it show the image when you paste the image's url to browser? if it's not, then it will not display the image in your app

Comment: It shows the image. then after a couple of seconds, the error shows in call stack.

Comment: can i see your code? I think that the problem is how to pass your url to your NetworkImage but not NetworkImage error